# Is there a way to keep "Loading..." animation running while user is navigating to another page?

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser

This question is a little bit tricky as I do not fully know which category / language / technology / area it falls.

Occassionally we're forwarding our user to another a form is submitted and handled. The form submission is done with [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)'s `.ajaxSubmit()` call, to provide feedback for user and if any error occurs, to give smooth ability to correct the errors.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var loading = $('<img src="loading.gif" />');
    $('#form').append(loading);
    $('#form').ajaxSubmit({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d) {
            if (d.errors) {
                loading.remove();
                // Handle the errors
            } else {
                // Forward the user to the next address, given by the server
                document.location = d.forward_to;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

While the user is getting forwarded to the next page, the loading.gif animation is stopped. This confuses the user.

I can confirm that this appens at least with Firefox and Chrome. **Is there a way to keep loading indicator running while user is navigating to the next page** (before the next page is rendered)?

Stopping the animations could be (intentional or unintentional) behavior of the browser application itself and thus completely uncontrollable by the web developer. However, I could not find any material that confirms it, so still looking for some solution - or alternative ways to do the indicator.

Comment: you alert/display a message to the user explaining what is happening

Comment: No, you have no control over that level of browser behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Beetroot-Beetroot. Do you have some references regarding this, I would be happy to "know the backgrounds"? It is really intentional that browser animations MUST be stopped before navigation happens?

Comment: Ville, this may well be mentioned somewhere on the web but as far as I know, it's an unspecified feature of browser behaviour. My statement is based on the undoubted fact that at some point browsers must stop working with an outgoing page and start working with the incoming page. I'm not sure whether browsers actively inhibit outgoing animations or whether rendering the incoming page simply robs the processor/graphics card of the capacity to maintain current animations. If I'm right in assuming that this aspect is unspecified, then the various browsers may well behave differently.

Comment: Just a thought, it's possible that Flash graphics may be different in this regard from animatged gifs/pngs.

Comment: Well, thanks again. I would be happy to accept your comment as an answer to my question... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Beetroot-Beetroot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142252/beetroot-beetroot) answered my question in the question comments: you *cannot* control the browser behavior at this level.